# Having Trouble Connecting to Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) using Python's SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy

I set up the Cloud SQL instance on Google Cloud Platform and followed the official instructions, but don't seem to be able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance. When I try to do a sanity check and access the PostgreSQL db through Cloud Shell, I'm able to connect successfully though.

Could someone please help - I would be much obliged.

Code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://<user>:<pass>@<public IP Address/<table>')

engine.connect()
```

Error:

```
Is the server running on host "XX.XX.XXX.XX" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port XXXX?
```

Comment: Your error message means either the wrong IP address or Cloud SQL is blocking (not enabled) your IP address. In Google Cloud SQL, did you whitelist your IP address? Did you read the documentation on how to set up a client and connect? Suggestion. Do NOT connect with the method that you are trying. Use Cloud SQL Proxy instead.

Comment: @RileyHun to dig further on the comment provided by John Hanley about using the Cloud SQL Proxy please refer to the proper [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#div-python-proxy). The connection statement should be something like this after importing `create_engine`  from the `sqlalchemy` as you already have shown on your code:

`engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://DATABASE_USER:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Cloud SQL proxy to connect to Cloud SQL from external applications.

In order to achieve this please follow the relevant [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#python).

The steps described would consist of:

1. Enabling the Cloud SQL Admin API on your Cloud Console.
2. Installing the relevant proxy client according to your OS.
3. Use any of the available methods to [authenticate the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#authentication-options).
4. Invoke the proxy with `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:5432 &`  ond your terminal and connect the proxy by changing your code and using SQLALCHEMY:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://DATABASE_USER:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/')
```

NOTE: the code above assumes you are not trying to connect to the proxy in a production environment and are using an [authenticated Cloud SDK client](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#gcloud) in order to connect to the proxy.

Comment: Why does this work though without even specifying the table name. I'm confused by this.

Comment: The code above is used to connect to the Cloud SQL instance itself. It gets the instance's name when you initialize the proxy on the step 4 previously mentioned. If you have already created a database (e.g. named MYDB) within the instance you could change the database URL accordingly: `'postgresql+psycopg2://DATABASE_USER:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/[MYDB]'`

Answer (score 3):

I found another way to connect to a PostgreSQL GCP instance without using the Cloud SQL Proxy.

Code:

```
import sqlalchemy

username = ''  # DB username
password = ''  # DB password
host = ''  # Public IP address for your instance
port = '5432'
database = ''  # Name of database ('postgres' by default)

db_url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
    username, password, host, port, database)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_url)

conn = engine.connect()
```

I whitelisted my IP address before trying to connect. (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#appaccessIP)

Answer (score 2):

This worked to me using the Cloud SQL Proxy on my personal computer and uploading the code to Google App Engine standard.

```
db_user = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_USERNAME')
db_pass = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD')
db_name = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE_NAME')
db_connection_name = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME')
if os.environ.get('GAE_ENV') == 'standard':
    db_uri = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{db_user}:{db_pass}@/{db_name}?host=/cloudsql/{db_connection_name}'
else:
    db_uri = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{db_user}:{db_pass}@127.0.0.1:1234/{db_name}'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = db_uri
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database client library, the socket (`/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432`) needs to be specified.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run) have this example for `SQLAlchemy`:

```py
db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]
db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]
db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")
cloud_sql_connection_name = os.environ["CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME"]

pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(

    # Equivalent URL:
    # postgresql+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>
    #                         ?unix_sock=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
        drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
        username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
        password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
        database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
        query={
            "unix_sock": "{}/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(
                db_socket_dir,  # e.g. "/cloudsql"
                cloud_sql_connection_name)  # i.e "<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>"
        }
    ),
    **db_config
)
```

Be aware that this example is with `pg8000` that uses `unix_sock` instead of `unix_socket` as socket identifier.